# Java inheritance ( local variable/ boolean in if)

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, local

I am studying the inheritance (Java), and I wrote the following code. The first part is the `CarBase`, and then I created a childclass 1, called `Bus`.

My idea is that first make a judgement if it is a bus, and by doing that, I need a boolean [`if(isBus)`], but when I wrote this code in Eclipse, there is a error message, said '`isBus` can not be resolved to a variable'.
Could some one please tell me how to solve this problem? Do I need to declare the boolean variable first?

Another question is about the declaration of local variables.
In the `getOnBus(0` method, I have a local variable called `temp`,I was taught that whenever using a local variable insided a method, I need to declare it first and then I shall be able to use it, but I saw someone use it directly like the following, I was wandering what's the difference between the two?

```
public class Bus extends CarBase {
    //Unique bus properties

    public int max_Passenger = 35;
    public int current_Passenger = 0;

    // unique bus method
    public boolean getOnBus(int p_amount) {
        if(isBus) {
            int temp = 0; // <===
            temp = current_Passenger + p_amount; // <===

            if( temp > max_Passenger) {
                return false;
            } else {
                current_Passenger = temp;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

or if there is difference if I use it without declaring it?

```
    public class Bus extends CarBase {
    //Unique bus properties

    public int max_Passenger = 35;
    public int current_Passenger = 0;

    // unique bus method
    public boolean getOnBus (int p_amount) {
        if(isBus) {
            int temp=current_Passenger+p_amount;  // <====

            if( temp > max_Passenger) {
                return false;
            } else {
                current_Passenger = temp;
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code is as following

First Part CarBase(parent)

```
public class CarBase {
    public int speed;
    public String name;
    public String color;
    public int maxSpeed = 90;

    // Method
    public void speedUp(int p_speed) {
        int tempSpeed = 0;
        if (p_speed > 0) {
            tempSpeed = speed + p_speed;
        }
        if (tempSpeed <= maxSpeed) {
            speed =tempSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Second Part Bus (Child1)

```
public class Bus extends CarBase {
    //Unique bus properties

    public int max_Passenger = 35;
    public int current_Passenger = 0;

    // unique bus method
    public boolean getOnBus (int p_amount) {
        if (isBus) {
            int temp = 0;
            temp = current_Passenger + p_amount;

            if (temp > max_Passenger) {
                return false;
            } else {
                current_Passenger = temp;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getOnBus` is a method of the `Bus` class, so why do you think you have to "make a judgement if it is a bus". You know for sure it is a Bus.

Comment: for the second question, there´s no difference. Additionally the `getOnBus` method does not make sense for me in the `Car` class, since it seems to be something restricted to a `Bus` only.

Comment: One question at a time please.

Comment: @Eran thanks so much for the help. the reason "isBus" becomes a problem for me, is that

Comment: @Eran    thanks so much for the comment. if I have a child class 2, which is SportsCar, the "getOnBus" method does not make any sense to SportsCar, but for Bus, In that case, if "make a judgement if it is a bus" is necessary or not?

Answer (score 0):

The point in using inherance is to abstract whether an object is a Car or a Bus, and write code that works no matter what is passed. To do so, you use abstract methods. Consider

```
abstract class Vehicle {
    private int occupied;

    public Vehicle() {
        occupied = 0;
    }

    public abstract int getCapacity();   // number of passengers

    public boolean board(int howmany) {
        if (occupied+howmany <= capacity) {
            occupied += howmany;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void unboard(int howmany) {
        occupied -= howmany;
    }
};

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public Car ()                { super(); } // just call the Vehicle() constructor
    public int getCapacity()    { return 5; }
}


class Bus extends Vehicle {
    public Bus()                { super(); } // just call the Vehicle() constructor
    public int getCapacity()    { return 32; }
}
```

you'd write every function to accept a Vehicle, and deal with it without the need to know if it is a bus or a car. (the following is a dumb function, just to give you an example)

```
void board_on_first_avaible(Vehicle[] x, int n) {
   for (int i=0; i<x.length; x++)
       if (x.board(n))
           return true; // board ok

   return false;  // couldn't board on anything
}
```

Note that you should design your code so that the functions are declared, abstract in Vehicle, for both Car and Bus. Thus `getOnBus()` would be a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

OK for the first point "isBus" is not declared, i can not see the point of checking in this method as you already know u are extending the CarBase but if you need to check you can do it like this

```
    if(this instanceof CarBase)
```

for the second point there is actually no effect for the change

```
   int temp=0; // <===
   temp= current_Passenger+p_amount; // <===
```

first you initialize with 0 then you assign the new value to it

```
   int temp=current_Passenger+p_amount;
```

here you initialize the temp with the value

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the Bus object 'isBus()' .... it IS a Bus, because you are defining the class as Bus!

So... if you were to create a new Bus object, you would say something like:

```
Bus BigYellowBus0001 = new Bus();
```

if you were to then say:

```
BigYellowBus0001.getOnBus(10);
```

You would NOT need to check if BigYellowBus0001 is a bus.... right?

In fact, you don't even need to name the method getOnBus().... it could just be getOn.

I think maybe you've gotten off on the wrong foot by deciding that Bus is a subclass of Car.

As for local variables, this just means variable that begin and end inside the method... so you did that nicely with your 'temp' variable.

To show that you understand how to access variables of the superclass from the child class, you could check the speed of the bus before letting people on:

```
public boolean getOnBus (int p_amount){
    if(speed = 0){
        int temp=0;
        temp= current_Passenger+p_amount;

        if( temp > max_Passenger){
            return false;
        } else{
            current_Passenger = temp;
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Sorry I did not quite get it when you said that "I think maybe you've gotten off on the wrong foot by deciding that Bus is a subclass of Car." I did think that bus is the subclass(child class) of Car/CarBase( super class). Did I understand wrong? I am a beginning of java, please guide me, thanks!

Comment: Yes, your code is fine... and you made your classes correctly, but what I'm saying is that in the REAL WORLD, maybe Bus is not a type of car.... so you may be making things difficult for yourself.  If you're allowed to change it so that your super class is VEHICLE... and so CAR *AND* BUS are a subclass of VEHICLE.  make sense?  just a suggestion, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

1. `isBus` is not declared that reason why you got this error
2. You doesn't need this check, because this method declared for `Bus` class and you are sure what it IS a `Bus` not a parent `CarBase` class (please use Vechicle instead of CarBase, it's much better on my opinion)
3. In Java 0 is default value for int, so you don't need to init variable before assign new value

So you can simplify `getOnBus()` like that

```
public boolean getOnBus (int p_amount) {
    int temp = current_Passenger + p_amount;
    if (temp > max_Passenger) return false;
    current_Passenger = temp;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To test if an object is an instance of a class you can to use `variable instanceof YourClass` which evaluates to a boolean